# React router redirect returns blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Can someone please explain why my redirect returns a blank page. The URL does update but `componentDidMount` doesn't fire and the rendered page is completely blank.

Path: `App.js`

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/login" />} />

            <PrivateRoute exact strict path="/mypage/:id">
              <POForm />
            </PrivateRoute>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `PrivateRoute.js`

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, auth, ...rest }) => {
  if (auth.isLoading) return null;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      exact
      strict
      render={({ location }) =>
        auth.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: {
                from: location
              }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Path: `POForm.js`

```
class POForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      newId: ''
    };

    this.createNewPurchaseOrder = this.createNewPurchaseOrder.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/get/po`, {})
      .then((res) => {
        const purchaseOrder = middlewarePurchaseOrder(res.data);
        purchaseOrder.isLoading = false;
        this.setState(purchaseOrder);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('err', err);
      });
  }

  createNewPurchaseOrder() {
    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/new/po`)
      .then((res) => {
        const po = res.data;

        po.newId = res.data._id;

        this.setState(po);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('err', err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.newId) {
      return <Redirect to={`/mypage/${this.state.newId}`} />;
    }

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            this.createNewPurchaseOrder();
          }}
        >
          createNewPurchaseOrder
        </button>
        <p>Page has loaded.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is rendering `POForm`? And can you update question with component code for `PurchaseOrderPage`?

Comment: @DrewReese sorry. I've updated. PurchaseOrderPage is POForm. Code has been updated.